# How to connect to Google Cloud SQL by SSL?

Tags: mysql, ssl, google-cloud-sql

I have created a ssl follow:

> https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/configure-ssl-instance

And read this document:

> https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-client#connect

After I created a new mysql instance and download the three pem files to local. I want to connect to that server:

```
mysql -u<USERNAME> -p -h <IP_ADDRESS> --ssl-ca=/local/path/to/server-ca.pem --ssl-cert=/local/path/to/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/local/path/to/client-key.pem
```

And type the password, again it said:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you follow the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-client) under the heading "Grant access to your instance? It links to [another document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/access-control#appaccess) that explains how to add IP addresses to Authorized Network list of your Cloud SQL instance. Even when using SSL certificates you must add the IP address as an Authorized Network.

Comment: Thank you. I did that and it worked well! That's the key point.